# Using NSPredicate CONTAINS with OR Swift 3

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I'm letting people search for music in CloudKit and using an NSPredicate based on genre, but getting an error. The predicate, "genres CONTAINS 'Rock'", works; however, I want to search through multiple genres, and i can't get things like "genres CONTAINS 'Rock' OR genres CONTAINS 'Hip Hop'" to work. I've tried using it with parenthesis, the logical || operator and other variations but cannot seem to get NSPredicate to work with CONTAINS and an OR operator.